How to set-up an insert from select call?
I am looking to insert data into a Supabase table using a select as the source.  Something like:
INSERT INTO foo (x, y)
SELECT x,y from widget where date > '12-12-2023';

However, I can find out a way of coding this using the Flutter Supabase client, and equally it doesn't seem to support a 'native SQL' function.
Any suggestions?

As the Supabase Flutter library is using PostgresRest API, a review of the API shows no support for native queries. This seems like a very odd omission.
